# SQL distinct not working in Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, adodb, vba

**The below code is one of the part in big project.**

***Below code counts records in the particular column.***

```
   Sub qareportds()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sname As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lrow As Integer

    sname = ActiveSheet.Name
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    value1 = weeknum

    con.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName

    If con.State = adStateClosed Then con.Open

    Dim query1 As String

    query1 = "SELECT COUNT(RETAIL_SKU) FROM [RETOUCH$]"

    rs.Open query1, con, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    Sheets("SHEET3").Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset rs

    rs.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Now i need to count the distinct values in the column .I used the below query

```
query1 = "SELECT COUNT(distinct RETAIL_SKU) FROM [RETOUCH$]"
```

But it throws below error ..

```
odbc driver does not support the requested properties
```

**Update Section:**

Is it possible to insert this query-

`SELECT COUNT(A.RETAIL_SKU) AS TotalCount FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RETAIL_SKU FROM [RETOUCH$]) AS A)`

into this

```
SELECT  REGION + '-' + STUDIO_SHORT_NAME,
    AVG(WorkedHours),
    AVG(OVERALL_CYCLE_TIME_HRS),
    'Studio Retouch - By Studio Locations - Non IA' as value1,
    13 as date1 
FROM    [RETOUCH$] 
WHERE   RETOUCH_LEVEL IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) 
    AND MERCHANT='Amazon' 
    AND SOURCE_TYPE='Studio' 
GROUP   BY REGION + '-' + STUDIO_SHORT_NAME
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` is not yet supprted. Try,

```
SELECT COUNT(A.RETAIL_SKU) AS TotalCount
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT RETAIL_SKU 
    FROM [RETOUCH$]
) AS A
```

Comment: Is it possible to help me with Update section in my Question ?